# Calendar / unity integration / thunderbird WITHOUT a google account

Tags: unity, thunderbird, calendar

As many others, I'm a looking for a calendar with Unity integration.
There is the calendar-indicator applet (ppa : atareo). But it means having a Google account. For some reasons, I don't want to use a google account to do that.
So, how could I do ?

It seems that using an Owncloud server could be a solution to avoid a google account, and can be used with TB without Evolution. But what about the Unity integration ? 
Have you some tips about that ?
I do hope a well integrated calendar App (= syncing with both Unity and TB) is going in Ubuntu next releases...

Thanks for your ideas...

Answer (score 1):

You have the anwser ! Owncloud actually offers a CalDav link to its calendars...

So you have 2 solutions :

1- Add a calendar feature to Thunderbird by installing "xul-ext-gdata-provider" available in the Ubuntu App center.

2- install evolution and add a calendar using its CalDav address

I didn't tried but I think it should work. 
[Edit] I tried the first solution, it works pretty well ! [/EDIT]

(Btw, owncloud is a great project and already offers lot of functionnalities despite its early development stage :o)

Answer (score 1):

### Syncevolution

SyncEvolution synchronizes personal information management (PIM) data via various protocols (SyncML, CalDAV/CardDAV, ActiveSync). It syncs contacts, appointments, tasks and memos. It syncs to web services or to SyncML-capable phones via Bluetooth.

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/SyncEvolution